# How to select all elements and remove a CSS class

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS function which on click is making the chosen element to be selected(is changing the background color) and should make all other elements to remove this class. However, for some reason `onClick` the "menu-category-hover" class is not removed.

```
function GetData(allMenuItems, theCategoryId) {
    
    // Remove selected class on other Elements
    allMenuEl = document.querySelectorAll('menu-category');
    for (var i = 0; i < allMenuEl; i++) {
        allMenuEl[i].classList.remove("menu-category-hover");
    }

    .....

    // On element Click
    var hoverEl = document.getElementById("menu_cat_" + theCategoryId);
    hoverEl.classList.add("menu-category-hover");
}

<div class="menu-category menu-category-hover" onclick="GetData(, 13)" id="menu_cat_13">
     <img src="/images/85783_burger.png" class="menu-home-image-img">
     <p class="menu-home-name">Burgers</p>
<div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `document.querySelectorAll('.menu-category')`? (notice the dot).

Comment: I forgot .length in the loop :(

Comment: There's no need to pass `theCategoryId` since you have it already inside the element's id.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```js
function GetData(allMenuItems, theCategoryId) {
    
    // Remove selected class on other Elements 
    allMenuEl = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-category'); //<--- class indicator `.`
    for (var i = 0; i < allMenuEl.length; i++) { //<-- not added allMenuEl.length
        allMenuEl[i].classList.remove("menu-category-hover");
    }

    .....

    // On element Click
    var hoverEl = document.getElementById("menu_cat_" + theCategoryId);
    hoverEl.classList.add("menu-category-hover");
}
```